# Pandas column creation methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are many methods for creating new columns in Pandas (I may have missed some in my examples so please let me know if there are others and I will include here) and I wanted to figure out when is the best time to use each method. Obviously some methods are better in certain situations compared to others but I want to evaluate it from a holistic view looking at **efficiency**, **readability**, and **usefulness**.

I'm primarily concerned with the first **three** but included other ways simply to show it's possible with different approaches. Here's your sample `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
```

Most commonly known way is to name a new column such as `df['c']` and use `apply`:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x * 2)
df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Using `assign` can accomplish the same thing:

```
df = df.assign(c = lambda x: x['a'] * 2)
df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Updated via @roganjosh:

```
df['c'] = df['a'] * 2
df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Using `map` (definitely not as efficient as `apply`):

```
df['c'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: x * 2)
df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Creating a new `pd.series` and then `concat` to bring it into the `dataframe`:

```
c = pd.Series(df['a'] * 2).rename("c")
df = pd.concat([df,c], axis = 1)
df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Using `join`:

```
df.join(c)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  2
1  2  5  4
2  3  6  6
```

Comment: I'd argue that these are _not_ the most common ways. `df['c'] = df['a'] * 2`. Much more efficient than `lambda` because it will be vectorized.

Comment: Don't use `apply` for vectorized operations, such as `* 2`. Just multiply by the series. `df['c'] = 2*df.a` is what you want. No need to complicate

Comment: @RafaelC I've updated the question with that method. Obviously this is a very simple example and there's an optimal way to do add a column here but I'm more interested in other cases where it might not be so obvious.

Comment: Sometimes I like to use `assign` when doing on the fly analysis so, I can create a new copy of the dataframe and revert back to the previous copy for trouble shooting.   If you just do df['B'] = df['B'] *2 you've modified the data frame inplace.  Where if you used df1 = df.assign(b=df['b']*2), you now have a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: vectorized calls (`df['c'] = 2 * df['a']`) almost always win on both speed and readability.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/7954504) answer regarding what you can use as a "hierarchy" of options when it comes to performance.

---

In generally, if you have a `for i in ...` or `lambda` present somewhere in a Pandas operation, this (sometimes) means that the resulting calculations call *Python* code rather than the optimized C code that Pandas' Cython library relies on for vectorized operations.  (Same goes for operations that rely on NumPy ufuncs for the underlying `.values`.)

As for `.assign()`, it is correctly pointed out in the comments that this creates a copy, whereas you can view `df['c'] = 2 * df['a']` as the equivalent of setting a dictionary key/value.  The former also takes twice as long, although this is perhaps a bit apples-to-orange because one operation is returning a DataFrame while the other is just assigning a column.

```
>>> %timeit df.assign(c=df['a'] * 2)
498 µs ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r 7 -n 1000 df['c'] = df['a'] * 2
239 µs ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As for `.map()`: generally you see this when, as the name implies, you want to provide a *mapping* for a Series (though it can be passed a function, as in your question).  That doesn't mean it's not performant, it just tends to be used as a specialized method in cases that I've seen:

```
>>> df['a'].map(dict(enumerate('xyz', 1)))
0    x
1    y
2    z
Name: a, dtype: object
```

And as for `.apply()`: to inject a bit of opinion into the answer, I would argue it's more idiomatic to use vectorization where possible.  You can see in the code for the [module where `.apply()` is defined](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/apply.py): because you are passing a lambda, not a NumPy ufunc,  what ultimately gets called is technically a Cython function, [`map_infer`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1af2f6cd29385b481d7d3de1e1a30cf1a64e9eb6/pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx#L1418), but it is still performing whatever function you passed on each individual member of the Series `df['a']`, one at a time.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A succinct way would be:

```
df['c'] = 2 * df['a']
```

No need to compute the new column elementwise.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using lambda function?
You can easily achieve the above-mentioned task easily by

```
df['c'] = 2 * df['a']
```

This will not increase the overhead.